# Grails Dependency Resolution Issue

Tags: grails, ivy

I'm having a problem on my machine where a specific dependency is not being resolved causing a `ClassNotFoundException` at runtime. Running `grails dependency-report` on my machine shows the artifact in question as having no dependencies, while on another developer's machine it shows dependencies properly.

Why would grails on my machine think the artifact has no dependencies, yet on another developer's machine the dependencies are correctly shown?

All other dependencies are resolved. Just this one artifact is not having its dependencies resolved on my machine.

Environment: Grails 1.3.7, Java 1.6.0_29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. It had to do with our local Artifactory having a bad pom. Our artifactory is actually composed of multiple repositories that are exposed as one virtual repository. The artifact in question was contained in two of those repos. One of the repos had a pom showing no dependencies for the artifact. This repo took precedence in the "virtual" view. We removed the corrupted version and then things started working.

How/why our Artifactory got this pom is still a mystery. But somehow it happened between the time my co-worker built out their environment and when I built out mine.

Comment: You can review the access log ($ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs/access.log) and check if perhaps someone redeployed this POM file. Binary content doesn't go corrupt willy nilly.

Comment: Maybe the term "Artifactory corrupted" is too strong for the situation. It doesn't look from your description that the server storage is corrupted in any way. More looks like a bad pom.

Comment: Agreed corrupted was a bad choice for the description. Changed to just "bad pom". Thanks for the comment!